# Is there any way in Laravel to authenticate user in external API and save it to local session so that, I can use all User:: and Auth:: functions?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have a requirement where I should login and register users through external API (no local database). How can I login user with external API so that, I can use all Laravel User:: and Auth:: features?

Comment: Do you have an API endpoint wherein you can authenticate users from the external API?

Comment: you can use  Auth::login($user, true) or  Auth::loginUsingId($userId, true);

Comment: @rkg yes, I have. In response I get user credentials. I want to store it in session like Laravel does and have the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Auth::login()`. Here is some example code you can modify to your specific API calls.

```php
$response = $api->login($credentials);

$user = User::findByApiId($response->id);

Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: what about guards?

Comment: Do this in a middleware before the guards are run. To prevent calling the auth API every request store the API response in a session variable and use this in subsequent requests: `session(['api_id' => $apiUserId])`.